# To change the 30-second time limit in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, rate-limiting

I find myself correcting typos rather often. So often, in fact, that I need to wait 30 seconds to fix typos in my comments sometimes.

It would be nice if

- I could delete my own comments in the first five seconds after they were posted

  - such comments didn't generate notifications
- my comments became public only if I did not remove them in the five-second period
- I could post a new comment without waiting if I removed one

This would be a great improvement to SO.

Please, either change the 30-second time penalty **or** decrease it to 15 seconds.

Comment: Jeff - just like to add a "me too". Could you clarify why this was declined?

Answer (score 15):

I'd either like to see an edit capability for my own comments, or I'd like to see this time limit waived once, for 30 seconds, if I've deleted one of my own comments. This would allow me to immediately replace the deleted comment, without permitting spam - it would be one deleted comment exchanged for one new one.

Comment: I'd love to edit my comments. I've made a typo, had somebody respond to the comment, and then realize that I made said typo. Would be nice to be able to edit it, since deleting then reposting would only be confusing.

Comment: YES!  this would be a great feature...

Comment: This is perfect. At least once a day I post a comment, realize I wanted to say something just a little bit differently, delete it, and sit there for 30 seconds waiting for it to let me post it again. I know 30 seconds doesn't seem like much but it'd be nice to be able to just do it again or quickly edit it (although editing would be a more extensive feature over just waiving the limit after a delete, I would imagine)

Comment: Editing comments would be great. I suggest a friendfeed style comment editing.

Comment: on the backend, the implementation should be pretty simple: when a comment is deleted which was posted less than 30 seconds ago, unset the "time of last comment" value.  spammers would still be limited to one comment per 30 seconds.

Comment: I wanted that capability just now on MSO.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a problem with 30 seconds, and it keeps people from really spamming things up. I don't think there should be that big of a deal to wait an extra 15 seconds to post another comment.

Comment: Agreed            .

Comment: 15 seconds isn't too much, unless you're the kind of person who needs to microwave Pop-Tarts...On-the-box directed microwaving time: 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Could we remove this restriction for people who are 10K+ and commenting on their own answer?

This is the case I most frequently run into the comment restriction.  I occasionally get multiple follow up questions in the form of comments that I want to respond to individually.  It's a real pain to want to give feed back but have to wait for that time limit to expire.

Comment: I support your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a system like Digg uses for its comment system.  Where you can edit your comment for X amount of time before it becomes 'locked' and is unable to be edited further.  That way you can fix your typos and stuff right off the bat, but after that it's either live with it or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just type too fast, and if I'm replying to a number of comments, I get frustated at the restriction. It's not about editing posts for me, it's about putting a number of replies in to a number of different comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the 30s limit is unchanged, it would be helpful to have a counter displayed in the notification window letting me know when the time has elapsed.

Comment: This is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

I might have supported this request back when it was asked, had I seen it. However, now that we can edit comments for a few minutes after they're posted, this no longer seems necessary.