# How about decreasing the allowed time between comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can we get x comment votes per x minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds)
>   [To change the 30-second time limit in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/to-change-the-30-second-time-limit-in-comments)

I often read through the answers to a question first and then start to comment. And very often I write comments faster than one per 30 seconds... it is very annoying to have to wait for that time to pass =/

How about decreasing that time limit? I'm sure it is there to prevent flooding of some sorts, but is 30 seconds really necessary? How about lowering it to 5-10 seconds?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/to-change-the-30-second-time-limit-in-comments/4790

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382

Comment: Eric, that's about votes per second, not comments per minute.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, but I do not think that it is a problem. There really isn't a need to make it any faster (by that I mean there isn't exactly a requirement for comments to be speedy like answers would be).

Overall I wouldn't mind if it changed, but I don't think it is any type of priority at all.