# 30 seconds per comment doesn't help

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To change the 30-second time limit in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/to-change-the-30-second-time-limit-in-comments)

When I jump into a question I'm active in, I want to be able to reply to a number of answers, and then get back to work/family/whatever. Maybe I just type too fast, but the 30 second thing drives me crazy.

Surely it's there to stop spammers, so perhaps it could be relaxed after a particular reputation level is reached? (Perhaps 200?)

And yes, this is a different question to [To change the 30-second time limit in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/to-change-the-30-second-time-limit-in-comments), which is focussed on being able to edit/delete comments. I just want to be able to post a bunch of one-liners, which I reckon I type in about 15 seconds each.

Every time I see that red box appear it frustates me and makes me want to spend less time here.

Comment: I agree.

Comment: and now ... I'm waiting ... for the .. stupid... red ... box to go away.

Comment: Duplicate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/to-change-the-30-second-time-limit-in-comments

Comment: Hi Barack... I posted in the question as to why I considered it a different question to 1982. You don't agree, obviously?

Comment: "Please, change the 30-second time penalty OR at least decrease it to 15 seconds". The reasons *why* the change was requested does not make the request original. You're still asking for the exact same thing. It has also already been declined.

Comment: Hmmm... but couldn't a new reason for the request could influence the decision maker.

Comment: !!! It doesn't let me delete the question. Too many upvoted answers.

Comment: It will be closed in time. As for influencing the answer, not in this case. There's very explicit reasons why this limit is in place to begin with. Heck, Jon Skeet still gets captchas if he posts too quickly.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a little part of me that wouldn't mind picking up the Disciplined badge if I can delete the question myself. But the answer that was posted is stopping me doing that.

Comment: Bizarrely - if I pick up that badge, I'll have more badges here than on SO.

Comment: This question is closed as an exact duplicate, but it's not an exact duplicate.  The other question is asking about some complicated proposal involving the ability to edit comments, or delete a comment and post a new one, and somesuch.  This question is asking about changing the way that rate-limiting of comments works.  This question has a totally different proposal.  I realize it was closed by Jeff Atwood and this is all unlikely to ever change (because Jeff says so), but I wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the goal of time between comments is not only to prevent spamming (and note, just because you've gained rep doesn't mean you account can't be compromised), but it also helps disinsentivize commenting a lot and I think that is a very important thing. Comments are not the goal of the site, they're necessary and useful, but I don't believe the system needs to make it easier to comment more.

Comment: No,but if there's a question I feel passionate about, then I'd like a shorter limit.

Comment: @yshuditelu - if you delete this answer, I'll delete the question and let the discussion continue on question 1982.